# Solving "ugly" equations

Tags: exponential-function, systems-of-equations, lambert-w

$k$, $c_1$ and $c_2$ are unkowns, while others are given. How can I solve the equations?

$$
\begin{cases}
k\left( {c_1 e^{\pi k} + \frac{c_2}{e^{\pi k}}} \right)^{(1 + 2\theta)/\theta} =  - \theta^2\tau \\
k(c_1 + c_2)^{(1 + 2\theta)/\theta} = \theta^2\tau \frac{e^ -\theta\eta - 1}{e^{-\theta\eta} + 1}\\
k\left( \frac{c_1}{e^{\pi k}} + c_2 e^{\pi k} \right)^{(1 + 2\theta)/\theta} = \theta^2\tau 
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: If you treat $k$ as a "known" variable, you can easily modify this system to be a system of three linear equations in $c_1$ and $c_2$. Solving this system would yield a solution for $c_1$ and $c_2$ in terms of $k$, as well as a potentially useful consistency criterion in terms of $k$ that must be satisfied. Solving for $k$ is going to be a whole lot less fun, and probably involve the Lambert W function.

Comment: Is there any restriction on the unkwons and constants? All of them can be any real number or is there any that has to be strictly positive/negative?

Comment: What is $-1^{ \theta / (1 + 2\theta)} $?

Comment: The constants are all positive real numbers and no restriction on unkwons @AugSB

Comment: $\theta \in \mathbb{R_+}$ @N74

Comment: $-1$ raised to a real is a complex number. If you divide the first equation by the second you will see that the solution can be real only if the exponent is natural. Too bad in that case no solution can be found.

Comment: OK. thank you very. I will try to find a numerical solution.